# Adverb modifier in action

Tags: adverbs, modifiers

What does the adverb ever modify in the sentence?

> “They experienced the coldest weather ever.”

Answer (score 0):

This is a fascinating question.

First of all, you are right to parse ‘ever’ as an adverb.  And we have been brought up to think that adjectives qualify nouns, whereas adverbs modify verbs.  This is what I was taught in primary (elementary) school, and, as far as I know, is taught today.

But in your example, it looks as if the adverb ‘ever’ must modify the superlative **adjective** ‘coldest’.

In fact, adverbs can be and and are regularly used to modify adjectives. This is recognised in Greenbaum’s *Oxford English Grammar*.

**”An adverb is a word that typically functions as a premodifier of an adjective or another adverb or as an adverbial.”**. [glossary]

What it cannot modify is a noun.  At least not usually.  I suppose *Neverland* could be a sort of exception.

His stricter definition of *adverb* [4.26 page 141] Illustrates the complex diversity of this part of speech.

**”Adverbs are a heterogeneous class. varying in their functional and positional ranges.  They constitute a series of overlapping subclasses, and some of them belong to more than one subclass.... ”**

What about *the man with a golden gun* or the **cat on a hot tin roof?  Aren’t the two prepositional phrases adverbial?  Yes, they are.

I recommend Greenbaum (above) as an authoritative account of adverbs and adverbial especially 4.26-8.  He tackles *ever* in 5.46 as a *postmodifier*, functioning as an *intensifier*.  His example [**1**], is not quite the same as yours.  He cites “never ever try to do chemistry experiments live”, where *ever* is a postmodifier intensifying the adverb *never*.

Nevertheless, in your case, it could be argued that *ever* is, in terms of *usage*, being used as a postmodifier, intensifying the adjective *coldest*.